# Why won't the values in my Array safe?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C. I wanted to create a program, where the user can fill an array with numbers, set a specific number into a certain array-register or read the value of a register.
Everything works so far except the reading value. I always get a 0 returned, why?
here's my code of the getValue();

```
void getValues(int getArray[]){



fflush(stdin);
printf("which slot do you want to read?\n");
gvinput = getchar();
ptr = getArray[gvinput];
printf("The value is: %d \n",ptr);
start();
}
```

and here's the whole code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int* ptr;
int list[200];
int x = 0;
int i = 0; // variable used by for-Loop in setList
int j = 0; // variable used by for-Loop in getList
int c; // C used for new Game
int input;
int g1;  //Value for getValue
int option; //start Value
int gvinput;


int main()
{
    start();
    return 0;
}


void setList(int sizeOfList)
{
    for (i = x; i <= sizeOfList; i++)
    {

        list[i] = i;

    }
}

void getList()
{
    for(j = x; j < i ; j++ )
    {
        printf("At %d we got the value %d with the adress %d\n",j,list[j],&list[j]);
    }
}

void startList()
{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter number between 0 and 30\n ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if(input > 30 || input == 0)
    {
        printf("The Number is not between 0 and 30\n");
        startList();
    }
    setList(input);
    getList();
    fflush(stdin);
    start();
}



void setValues(int l[])
{
    fflush(stdin);
    int v;
    int loc;
    printf("please enter what value you want to safe\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Where do you want to save it?\n");
    scanf("%d",&loc);
    l[loc] = v;
    printf("we got at slot %d the value %d\nThe Adress is: %d.",loc,l[loc],&l[loc]);
    start();
}

void getValues(int getArray[]){



fflush(stdin);
printf("which slot do you want to read?\n");
gvinput = getchar();
ptr = getArray[gvinput];
printf("The value is: %d \n",ptr);
start();
}

void start(){
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("[L] = generate Slots\n");
    printf("[S] = set a Value at specific slot\n");
    printf("[G] = get a Value from a specific slot\n");
    option=getchar();
    if(option == 'L'){
        startList();
    }
    if(option == 'S'){
        setValues(list);
    }
    if (option =='G'){
        getValues(list);
     }
}
```

would be great if someone could help and give tips

Comment: `printf("The value is: %d \n",*ptr);`

Comment: fflush(stdin)->undefined behavior

Comment: @KaustavRay: not on Linux; not on Windows.

Comment: @moeCake program crashes when I use *ptr :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your code should be compiling with warnings; pay heed to those warnings because they are telling you that your program is wrong. (If you are not getting warnings, you need to change the compilation options on your compiler, or get a better compiler!) Remember, the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do at the moment.  Also, the `getchar()` in `GetValues()` is probably getting the newline that came after the `G` you entered.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the hint, you are right, I have alot of warnings but it still compiles that's why I assumed I did something right :D I will check the page out, i am sorry for that behavior.. thank you again

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not understand ! Can you please elaborate ? :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I fixed the warnings, yet I still can't manage to get the correct values :/

Comment: @KaustavRay: Microsoft explicitly documents that `fflush(stdin)` on Windows removes unread characters from the input buffer. GNU glibc also documents that `fflush(stdin)` removes unread characters from the input buffer.  Miraculously, they do the same.  And it is not just `stdin` but any input channel.  It means that if the input is a terminal and there are characters that have been entered by the user but not yet read by `getc()` or its equivalents, those characters are discarded.  Stray newlines, etc.  Actually, it is a useful feature.  It is **not** standard C or standard POSIX, though.

Comment: `gvinput = getchar();
ptr = getArray[gvinput];` `gvinput` : It is necessary to convert to a numeric from character.

Comment: 'To iterate is human, to recurse divine', but in the context of `StartList()`, recursion is wasteful and iteration is better.  You should check that `scanf()` reads a value (`if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1) { ...process error... }` and check for negative numbers in the input.  One simple debugging aid is to print the value you just read.  If you enter the value 30, the first 31 elements of the list are initialized; the remaining 169 are left at zero.  `%d` is not the correct format for printing addresses; use `%p`.  Global variables like `i` and `j` are horrendous and bug-inducing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler solved, your tips were useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is getting thoroughly confused by the use of `getchar()`. When you press keys such as <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, there are *two* chars returned from `getchar()`. The first call will return `'G'`, then the next time you call `getchar()` it will return `'\n'` (the Enter key).

To solve this, replace calls to `getchar()` with code such as:

```
char buf[80];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
option = buf[0];
```

The call to `fgets()` will get an entire line of text including the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress, and then `option = buf[0];` extracts the first character typed on the line.

After you do that, you can remove all the `fflush(stdin)` which is technically (according to the C standard) undefined behaviour and doesn't really do what you want.

EDIT: You'll also want to do the same with your calls to `scanf()`. That function isn't really intended for interactive use at all. Use `fgets()` as above, and then call `atoi()` to convert the entered string to an int.

ANOTHER EDIT: You are using

```
gvinput = getchar();
```

which assigns the *ASCII value* of the character typed into `gvinput`. If you type `4`, then `gvinput` will get 52, not 4. Use the same method you use in `setValues()` to get the value of `loc`.

Comment: Note the discussion in the comments to the main question about `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: That's true, but it's still *technically* undefined behaviour.

Comment: It depends on what is doing the defining.  If you take the manuals for the system you're working on and the system happens to be Windows or Linux, then the behaviour is defined.  It is defined by the implementation, but not by the standard.  If you state 'the C standard says that `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour', then you're on safer territory -- it does do that.

Comment: I still get a 0 returned,

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It sure doesn't seem to "remove unread characters from the input buffer" or anything of the sort on my nearest Linux box. Test program (pardon the formatting): `#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", c);
    fflush(stdin);
    c = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
`

Comment: I still get a 0 returned :  `void getValues(int getArray[]){
fflush(stdin);
char buf[80];
printf("which slot do you want to read?\n");

fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
gvinput = buf[0];
printf("The value is: %d \n",getArray[gvinput]);
start();
}`  Im very grateful for your help everyone

Comment: @Makaveli: `gvinput = buf[0]` is the same problem. Try `gvinput = atoi(buf)`.

Comment: The Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 deriviative) manual says: _For input streams, `fflush()` discards  any  buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application._ For file-based input, that can mean a lot of data.  Running your program on a terminal, though, didn't produce the output I expected, leaving open the question of what the man page means.  However, the man page does say the `fflush(stdin)` is defined behaviour, even though neither of us yet knows what the defined behaviour is.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getValues(int getArray[]){
fflush(stdin);

printf("which slot do you want to read?\n");
scanf("%d",&gvinput);
fflush(stdin);
printf("The value is: %d \n",getArray[gvinput]);
start();
}
```

this is the correct code just in case